# Dynamic feature release build failed with duplicate resources

Tags: android, android-resources, dynamic-feature

I am creating one sample to check dynamic feature delivery provided by android. I have project structure in following way. Base project **app** and one dynamic feature **sample_dynamic_feature**. All the setup required for dynamic feature delivery is in place. The problem comes when I add any layout file or .xml file with same name in base module as well as in dynamic module. I added **activity_main.xml** in both base application as well as in dynamic module. I got the following error :

**What went wrong:**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: Modules 'base' and 'sample_dynamic_feature' contain entry 'res/layout/activity_main.xml' with different content.
```

**Works fine with :**

```
Above setup works fine in debug mode.
./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

**Failing with:**

```
In case of release mode it gives me above error.
./gradlew bundleDebug
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

**Full stack-trace:**

> Exception is:
>           org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>           Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: Modules 'base' and 'sample_dynamic_feature' contain entry 'res/layout/activity_main.xml' with different content.
>                   at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
>                   ... 31 more
>           Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: Modules 'base' and 'sample_dynamic_feature' contain entry 'res/layout/activity_main.xml' with different content.
>                   at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
>                   at kotlin.io.CloseableKt.closeFinally(Closeable.kt:53)
>                   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask.bundleModules(PackageBundleTask.kt:121)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>                   ... 44 more
>           Caused by: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: Modules 'base' and 'sample_dynamic_feature' contain entry 'res/layout/activity_main.xml' with different content.
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException$Builder.build(ValidationException.java:49)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException$Builder.build(ValidationException.java:41)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.EntryClashValidator.checkEqualEntries(EntryClashValidator.java:66)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.EntryClashValidator.validateAllModules(EntryClashValidator.java:52)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.ValidatorRunner.validateBundleModulesUsingSubValidator(ValidatorRunner.java:75)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.ValidatorRunner.lambda$validateBundleModules$4(ValidatorRunner.java:64)
>                   at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:407)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.ValidatorRunner.validateBundleModules(ValidatorRunner.java:63)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.BundleModulesValidator.validate(BundleModulesValidator.java:101)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildBundleCommand.validateInput(BuildBundleCommand.java:244)
>                   at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildBundleCommand.execute(BuildBundleCommand.java:162)
>                   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable.run(PackageBundleTask.kt:200)
>                   at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)
>                   ... 48 more

What does this bundle makes difference?

Answer (score 1):

While generating an APK using assembleRelease or assembleDebug, the build system generates different apk's for different dynamic features. One for base and one for each dynamic feature. So there is no resource conflict.

In case of generating app bundle, the build system would have conflict, since the artifact that is generated is one single artifact which is the aab file.

Comment: Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Just have the layout names different in the base module and the dynamic module. 2 layouts of the same name would always conflict.

Comment: What if you use two libraries who have the same resource name?

Comment: @PrimožKralj Could you find a solution to this if the libraries have the same resource name?

Comment: No, I didn't :(